# Can't set Android target after update sdk rev.21 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

After update Android SDK revision 21 for building application with Android 4.2. But now, I can't set Android Project Build target anymore.

Steps in procedure:

1. Updated Android SDK platform and platform tools to revision 21 via Android SDK manager.
2. Updated ADT plugin for eclipse to revision 21.
3. Restart Eclipse.

This is Android entry in Eclipse Preferences.
[image: Android Preferences]

This is my project's properties:
[image: Project Properties]

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At least, I have to install the latest Eclipse IDE to make it works.**

**My old eclipse version:**

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>
> Version: 1.4.2.20120213-0813
>
> Build id: 20120216-1857

**and the latest:**

> Eclipse Platform
>
> Version: 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO
>
> Build id: M20120914-1800