# How can i retrieve Android SDK and Eclipse ADT Plugin from revision 21 to revision 20

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I make a question here: [Can't set Android target after update sdk rev.21 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409373/cant-set-android-target-after-update-sdk-rev-21-in-eclipse).

I guess there are some bugs in eclipse with new Android SDK revision. Now I try to retrieve the older revision to continue developing.

How can i retrieve Android SDK and Eclipse ADT Plugin from revision 21 to revision 20?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to do a rollback in Eclipse.  In Eclipse 4.x go to `Help --> About Eclipse --> Installation Details -->  Installation History`, from there you can revert to a previous setup.

Comment: Thanks Antew. Your solution even works with Eclipse 3.7. But i could only retrieve Eclipse ADT plugin. I can't go back Android SDK to revision 20.

Comment: I combined your answer and SkyStar's answer to make it works. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this file

ADT

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.3.zip

SDK

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r20-windows.zip

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks SkyStar. I will try with your sugestion to go back to SDK revision 20.

Comment: remember, you can copy the contents of platforms folder into a new one
To save time for downloading emulators

Comment: I combined your answer and Antew's answer to make it works. Thanks you very much.